# How to import data from access to spss with odbc?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, spss

I try to import my access database (Access 2016 64-bit) into IBM Spss (Version 25.0.0.1 64-bit). Therefore I installed new drivers for ODBC (Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *accdb 32/64-bit)).
Everything looks good so far. In Spss I go for file->import Data-> Database-> New Query and chose the MS Access Database. Now I can select tables from my database, set joins 
and filter, change data types but in the end I got an empty data sheet if I click on finish. The wierdest thing is: In 10% of the cases I actually got my data into the sheet and it works fine.
In 90% of the cases my error message by Spss is (unknown error):

```
GET DATA 
/TYPE=ODBC 
/CONNECT='DSN=Test1234;DBQ=C:\Users\S\Desktop\DBSMDPseudoTest.mdb;  DriverId=25;FIL=MS '+ 
'Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;' 
/SQL='SELECT HERKUNFT_CD '+ 
  'FROM AOP' 
/ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=255. 

Fehler.  Befehlsname: GET DATA 
Unknown error 
Die Ausführung dieses Befehls wurde gestoppt. 

CACHE. 
EXECUTE. 

Fehlernummer 105.  Befehlsname: EXECUTE 
Dieser Befehl ist erst gültig, wenn eine Arbeitsdatei definiert wurde. 
Die Ausführung dieses Befehls wurde gestoppt. 
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
```

What I've done so far:

> 1. I tried to reinstall Spss aswell as Office and some odbc drivers. I also installed th Access Database Engine 2016 for 64-Bit and 32-Bit.
> 2. I tried everything running on 32-bit instead of 64-bit.
> 3. I tried to change change the datatype from accdb to mdb, but it doesnt help either.
> 4. I turned off my firewall during installation and data-import.
> 5. I tried to use syswow64\odbcad32.exe to run on 32-bit.
> 6. I tried some other data types (xls,...) and everythig works fine
> 7. I also tried different tables not only one.

I don't get it: I can watch my data in the data wizard in spss, but if try to import it by clicking finish same unknown error occurs in 90% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful at all...
I don't work with MS Access myself but do a lot of importing data from external sources into spss and have found the spss native options for import of predefined datatypes to be extremely unreliable. 
Also I second your observation that the data wizards preview seems to be dissociated with the actual import engine - whyever that is the case.

In your case you might encounter a problem having to do with localization - try to change your system language (!!) to english, and, just to be sure, reinstall spss and also chose english (us) as a language there afterwards. That sometimes helps. SPSS is also extremely picky when it comes to encoding of .txt or .csv files: I found ANSI to be working reliable.

Because I'm very paranoid about data and don't trust the spss wizard any more the only way I import into spss is via ANSI encoded CSV / delimited TXT files. Not sure how much work that would be with access data (and also you stated you already tried this), but just to have the plain data it works like it should.

Frohes Fest!